# Get JSON from function A and pass to it Function B in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I make a sync http calls, I have 2 shared services to do the calls first is to fetch all the data then do `ngFor` to render the items say to make button.

Shared Service

```
getOrderId(id) {
    return this.http.get('www.site.com/api/Order/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
getOriginSite () {
    return this.http.get('www.site.com/api/Orders?originSite=2')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

So `getOrdersFromOrigin()` is being called first in the `ngOnInit`

```
getItemOrigin() {
        this.sharedService.getOriginSite ()
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.itemPrepare= data.Results;
          })
      }

    <div *ngFor="let prepare of itemPrepare">
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="getOrderId(prepare.Id); modal.open();">{{ prepare.Id }}</button> <br/><br/>

     <modal #modal>
      <modal-body>
            <p>{{ customerName }}</p>
      </modal-body>
      <modal-footer>
         <button (click)="modal.close()" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
         <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="updateOrder(prepare.Id)">It's Ready</button>
       </modal-footer>
      </modal>
    </div>
```

this creates buttons in the UI then when I click this it calls another API, this will also display some data in the modal above but it has to wait for few seconds to display because it has to wait for the call to be finished. This also results for the `this.currentOrderJosn` to be `undefined` when I pass it down to `updateOrder()`.

```
getItemJson(id) {
this.sharedService.getOrderId(id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    // Use this data for the POST
    this.currentOrderJson = data;
    this.customerName = data.Results.Customer.FirstName;
  })
}

updateItemJSON(id) {
    // Returns as undefined
    console.log(this.currentOrderJson)
}
```

So how can I make these calls to be in sync so it doesn't have to wait for few seconds to display the data and so I can use `this.currentOrderJSON()` in `updateOrder()`.

Comment: Please post more code. Where is the first `(click)`? How is the modal opened? What kind of modal is it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've updated my post, the first `(click)` happens from an `ngFor` within the modal is where the 2nd `(click)` is going to happen. Modal is a module called `ng2-bs3-modal`

Answer (score 0):

```
  getOrderId(id) {
    return this.preparedOrderId = this.http.get('www.site.com/api/Order/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .toPromise();
  }
```

```
(click)="getOrderClickHandler(id)"
```

```
getOrderClickHandler() {
  getOrderId(id).then(id => updateOrder(id))
}
```

or

```
getOrderId(id) {
    this.http.get('www.site.com/api/Order/' + id)
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(val => this.preparedOrderId = val);
  }
```

```
(click)="updateOrder(prepare.Id)"
```

While the later assumes that you won't be able to close the dialog during the time it takes to get the response from the server.
With the former this can not happen because it's properly chained and `updateOrder()` won't be called before the id isn't available.

Comment: Oh okay, I will try this. How is it different from the code above? Will this give me the JSON of the item being pass in the getOrderId so I can `POST` in `updateOrder()`

Comment: I guess I don't understand that part of your question. If you want the JSON, then store the JSON instead of the id.

Comment: But I need the `Id` to do an API call `/api/Order/id` which is the `getOrderId()`.

Comment: I think I know the issue now, the `getOrderId()` seems slow to do a call so once I press `updateOrder()` when `getOrderId()` hasn't done the call yet it gives me `undefined`

Comment: If you're doing an async in getOrderId, then yes, but I can't tell because the code isn't in you question. If a call depends on the result of an async execution you **always** need to chain with `.map()` or some other operator of `observable` or `.then()` (in case you get a `Promise`).

Comment: I see, I've added my shared service code which is using `.map` and the `getItemOrigin()` is called first in `ngOnInit()` this does the `ngFor`. Where is `.then` being imported because I get `.then does not exist on type observable..`, I should replace `.subscribe()` to `.then()` instead?

Comment: `getOrderId()` won't do anything. You call it from `(click)="getOrderId(prepar.id)"` (without `.subscribe()` and  `getOrderId()` itself doesn't do a `.subscribe()`. Without `.subscribe()` the call `http.get(...)` call won't be made. And there is also nothing that handles the response. `res => res.json()` gets the JSON out of the response but it doesn't do anything with it, so it would just be dropped after it was received. I guess you want to assign it to a local property.

Comment: Currently it's too confusing what you actually try to accomplish. Would you mind editing your question and add a concise explanation about what you expect to happen from which actions.

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully its makes more sense.

Comment: for the first approach, I'm getting template error guessing instead of using `getOrderId()` for the fist call I use `preparedOrderId()`?  what's I'm going use in the 2nd call `updateOrder()`

Comment: Sorry, seems I was a bit confused. I forgot a `return` in `getOrderId()` and a closing `)` in the `(click)` handler. I'm not sure if `=>` can be used in templates. you might need to move the code to a method and call the method instead.

Comment: yeah `=>` didn't work in the template, the 2nd approach is similar to what I already have. Is doing a sync call a good approach in general?

Comment: I don't think it's a good approach. It will work as long as a response from the server arrives in short time, but depending on that is usually bad practice. Just move the code to a method so you don't have `=>` in the template and then call this method from the template.

Comment: Yeah the time span it takes to return the data back is like 1.5s, is that a long time? a spinny loader might be good so it shows something is happening? Sorry could you show me where to move it? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Looks like its still the same issue, its still waiting 1.5-1.8s to finish the call. I might just put a spinning loader to have a response to show while finishing the call, I think that's a better approach for UX purpose.

Comment: Hard for me to understand what the problem exactly is or what you try to accomplish. If you want `updateOrder` to be called immediately, you can do `let orderIdPromise = getOrderId(id); updateOrder(orderIdPromise);` and then in `updateOrder(idPromise) { /* do something while the id is fetched from the server */ idPromise.then(id => /* do something when the id becomes available */)` but not sure if this is what you're looking for.